# calling QSqlTableModel.setData from QML TableView delegate

Tags: python, qt, qml

My task is create an editable Qtableview for QSqlTableModel using QML template.

here is a part of qml template:

```
TableView {
 model: myModel
 delegate: Rectangle {
 TextInput {
  id: txt
  text: display
  onEditingFinished: {
   display = text
                    }
                }
}
```

and here is a model:

```
class customQSqlTableModel(QSqlTableModel):

    def __init__(self, db):
        super().__init__(db = db)
        self.setTable('main')
        self.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.EditStrategy.OnRowChange)
        self.select()
        self.setHeaderData(0, PySide6.QtCore.Qt.Orientation.Horizontal ,'descr')
        self.setHeaderData(1, PySide6.QtCore.Qt.Orientation.Horizontal, 'price')

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if super().setData(index, value, Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole):
            res = self.submit()
            if res == True:
                return True

        return False

    def flags(self, index) -> PySide6.QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag:
        return PySide6.QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable|PySide6.QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEnabled|PySide6.QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEditable
```

qml engine calls my customQSqlTableModel.setData method with role = Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole
so setData save changes only if i redefine role to EditRole while calling super method.

what im doing wrong?